# *ngIf creates an infinite loop and never resolves

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express

I'm working in angular and only want to display a certain form if certain values line up. I have the backend route working and tested with postman. Here is my code

> Blockquote
>   Angular Component HTML

```
<div *ngIf="canEdit()">
    ...
</div>
```

That ^ is currently the only thing calling the function

> Blockquote
>   Angular TS File

```
  canEdit() {
let username = this.currentUser.user.username;
let values = {
  "_id": this.org._id,
  "user": username
}
return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3001/users/compareUser', values, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
    result => {
      if (result.message == "All good!") {
        console.log(result);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  )
```

So these are the two parts, currently if I run this it results in an infinite loop, of console.log(result), which displays {result: "All Good!"} I'll share my backend route as well, which is express. Funny thing is if I just replace the function canEdit() to return true and maybe console.log some text so I see how many times it's being called, it's only being called the one time. However with the code I shared (TS) it never even acknowledges the 'return true' that is below console.log(result).

> Express route

```
    router.post("/compareUser", function(req, res, next) {
  let token = req.cookies.token;
  let id = req.body._id;
  let user = req.body.user;
  if (token) {
    Org.findById(id, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Could not find Organization"
        });
      } else {
        User.findOne({ username: user }).then(user => {
          if (!user) {
            return res.status(401).json({
              message: "Are you sure you exist?"
            });
          } else {
            if (user.username == result.username) {
              return res.status(200).json({
                message: "All good!"
              });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(404).json({
      message: "You must be logged in"
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a Subscription in the canEdit() method not a boolean you can fix this issue by adding a variable to the component class and using that one instead of the method:

```
valid = false;

ngOnInit() {
 this.canEdit();
}

 canEdit() {
let username = this.currentUser.user.username;
let values = {
  "_id": this.org._id,
  "user": username
}
this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3001/users/compareUser', values, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
    result => {
      if (result.message == "All good!") {
        console.log(result);
        this.valid = true;
      } else {
        this.valid = false;
      }
    }
  )
}
```

and in your template:

`<div *ngIf="valid"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

another approach (*) is return the observable itself and use | async

```
canEdit() {
   let username = this.currentUser.user.username;
   let values = {
      "_id": this.org._id,
      "user": username
   }
    //see that return an observable
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3001/users/compareUser', values, { withCredentials: true })
    //we use map to transform the response in a true/false
    .pipe(map(result=>{
        return result.message=="All good!"?true:false
    })
}
```

And

```
<div *ngIf="canEdit()|async">
    ...
</div>
```

(*)Complementary Leo's answer